# Error while installing matplotlib and pyplot in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, pycharm

I freshly installed python 3.10 and used it with PyCharm,I am on windows 10.
I installed the 'numpy' package, and it went fine.
I tried to install the 'matplotlib' but I got an error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\MEDVX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\MEDVX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-un3kpywl\\matplotlib_14231889845d46839010c545a31f9693\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\MEDVX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-un3kpywl\\matplotlib_14231889845d46839010c545a31f9693\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MEDVX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v8ijdjvm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\MEDVX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\include\site\python3.10\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

After that, I tried to update my pip, it updated to version latest version, but the error remained.

It says to `"Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at:

```
 'C:\Users\MEDVX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe'."`
```

but when I try to install/update in this directory it writes:

```
C:\Users\MEDVX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users     \\MEDVX\\pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried diffrent commands to check the pip version, or to install it but all of them return the same error, seen above.

I'd say that I am a tech noob and maybe the problem is that I am doing something dumb and obvious, I suspect I need to install it to another directory but I can't figure out which, or maybe it has to do with my PyCharm settings ?

I would appreciate all the help.

```
[Pycharm error][1]
[Updating my pip][2]
[error after updating the path pycharm told me][3]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlueL.jpg

EDIT:
I managed to install matplotlib by installing "matplotlib "Microsoft C++ Build Tools".
But, I am unable to install pyplot, same issue, even after updating my pip inside PyCharm it shows an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyplot
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simply, I had to install '[Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)'

I didn't manage to install pyplot in Pycharm but after combinations of, restarting my pc & PyCharm, updating pip throw my CMD and pycharm, enabling interactive mode, `matplotlib.pyplot` worked, using python 3.10\3.9 (didn't bother testing other ones after it worked)
it showed a graph, I used this code to check:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

fig, simple_chart = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()

simple_chart.plot(data)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```